# MS ACCESS or Excel formula or code to result in desired output column

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have some data that has a 1 to many relation. Below is dummy data to represent my data.  I have an ID that will have multiple ALT_IDs. Those Alt_IDs have a relation to a column called Alt_Spec_Code.  I need or desire an output column that would populate let's say ID_Spec_Code with only one of the Alt_Spec_Codes.

```
 ID          ALT_ID          ALT_SPEC_CODE          DESIRED_OUTCOME(ID_SPEC_CODE)
 123456      111111          PA                     PA
 123456      222222          N/A                    PA
 123456      121212          N/A                    PA
 654321      333333          N/A                    ST
 654321      444444          ST                     ST
 654321      434343          N/A                    ST
 987654      222222          N/A                    N/A
 987654      121212          N/A                    N/A
 987654      333333          N/A                    N/A
 456789      111111          PA                     BOTH
 456789      444444          ST                     BOTH
 456789      555555          N/A                    BOTH
```

I was thinking I could even do an update statement to update the Desired_Outcome field with the Max or maybe even doa row_number type query to rank the Alt_Spec_Code and then update Desired_Outcome field with the first value it finds. But then I wasn't sure how to handle the last scenario where it might be Both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
SELECT
    y2.ID,
    y2.ALT_ID,
    y2.ALT_SPEC_CODE,
    Switch
        (
            CountOfALT_SPEC_CODE Is Null, 'N/A',
            sub2.CountOfALT_SPEC_CODE = 2, 'Both',
            sub2.CountOfALT_SPEC_CODE = 1, sub2.MinOfALT_SPEC_CODE
        ) AS DESIRED_OUTCOME
FROM
    YourTable AS y2
    LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                sub1.ID,
                Count(sub1.ALT_SPEC_CODE) AS CountOfALT_SPEC_CODE,
                Min(sub1.ALT_SPEC_CODE) AS MinOfALT_SPEC_CODE
            FROM
                (
                    SELECT DISTINCT y1.ID, y1.ALT_SPEC_CODE
                    FROM YourTable AS y1
                    WHERE y1.ALT_SPEC_CODE<>'N/A'
                ) AS sub1
            GROUP BY sub1.ID
        ) AS sub2
    ON y2.ID = sub2.ID;
```

I didn't know how to explain that coherently.  You can figure out how it works by breaking out each subquery into a new Access query, starting from the lowest level, `SELECT DISTINCT ...`

But basically the strategy is to compute *CountOfALT_SPEC_CODE* and *MinOfALT_SPEC_CODE* for each *ID*.  Then the top-level `Switch` expression can use that information to compute *DESIRED_OUTCOME*.